# How to extend div to the entire page?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to set background color to the pages in my React app. I want to set a background color extending to the full page length and width but I cannot do that, for forms or tables extending beyond, I set height/width or min-height/min-width to 100% and I get the result for larger contents but for smaller contents,I get this:

I want to have the entire page of blue color.

[image]

This is my css file

```
.body
{
   margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
   background-color:#4086ef;
   padding:10px;
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
}
```

If I set height to 100vh, I get the undesired result but with contents going beyond the page.

(Content rendering is dynamic so I don't know when the content will go beyond and when not).

**EDIT:**
The table doesn't squeeze along when I compress the window and neither does the overflowing part follow the background color but the height follows the background color even when scrolled.

Comment: Add `min-height` to `100vh`

Comment: Are you adding the style to `<body>` . If so you have to remove the .  from .body in css

Comment: No it is an external css file.

Comment: the width does not work, if I open the Dev Tools, and scroll to the right, background is white, I have tried setting width and min-width:100vh;

Comment: add `min-width` to `100vw`

Comment: If you'd like to set a background for all your pages in react why not just set the background color on the body itself?

Comment: actually there are two separate workflows in the same app, and one workflow has to have a different background color, the white is the color in the body of app.js

Comment: @LaljiTadhani The width doesn't work at all, The content inside is a table, and even when I try to alter the margin, nothing happens

Answer (score 6):

You just need to add `height:100vh`.So that it will cover your whole screen.

Comment: Worked but with min-height:100vh, though adding 100vh extends the page length and gives a scrollign option when not needed. Also, what is the difference between % and vh? I know vh gives value relative to the browser height.

Comment: 100vh means 100% viewport height where 100%  means parent's element height.Usually both works same in body tag because its our parent element.Also if 100vh gives you scrollbar then you can set overflow:hidden property in body tag.But normally 100vh wont give scrollbar.There might be other reasons of the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

div {
    background: red;
    color: white;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    Test
</div>
```

Comment: Actually it is a react app and I have to assign each div some id or class, so I don't think * would work and including this in the body doesn't work either.

Comment: this is a common css

Comment: I am using modular approach, as you can see I have used **.body** instead of body, anyway I tried and it did not work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:
`height: 100% !important;`